# Why is this function slower after a simple change?

Tags: performance-tuning, function-construction

I have a function that calculates the rank of a restricted growth string defined like so,

```
rankKRGS[{}] = 0;
rankKRGS[string_] :=
 With[{n = Length@string, k = Max@string + 1, alone = !MemberQ[Most@string, Last@string]},
  rankKRGS@Most@string +
   If[alone, k*StirlingS2[n - 1, k], Last@string*StirlingS2[n - 1, k]]]
```

However, if I simply change the order of the addition to,

```
rankKRGS[string_] :=
 With[{n = Length@string, k = Max@string + 1, alone = !MemberQ[Most@string, Last@string]},
  If[alone, k*StirlingS2[n - 1, k], Last@string*StirlingS2[n - 1, k]]
   + rankKRGS@Most@string]
```

It performs much slower. As an example, consider this:

```
First@RepeatedTiming@rankKRGS[{0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 6, 10, 11, 12, 12, 0, 7, 1, 8, 3, 13, 9, 6, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 6, 18, 19, 20, 6, 21, 17, 22, 15, 23, 23, 15, 23, 22, 6, 24, 25, 6, 22, 17, 24, 6, 26, 17, 27, 28, 6, 24, 15, 27, 17, 29, 6, 25, 30, 6, 20, 15, 24, 24, 15, 23, 22, 6, 21, 28, 6, 31, 17, 27, 6, 20, 15, 20, 24, 17, 27, 6, 25, 23, 6, 24, 31, 17, 6, 21, 19, 23, 32, 33, 6, 19, 23, 29, 6, 25, 30, 6, 31, 19, 26, 15, 23, 22, 6, 23, 25, 24, 31, 15, 23, 22, 6, 24, 25, 6, 29, 25, 34}]
```

Before the change, it outputs `0.00206` on my machine. After the change, it outputs `0.0050`. It seems minor, but on large numbers of these strings it adds up.

Comment: Please provide a test case that shows the difference in speed that you are talking about, that we can run on our computers.

Comment: Please consider adding an example as @C.E. suggested. Otherwise, I am inclined to close this as "not enough information provided", although I don't want to because it seems like you've got something mysterious going on.

Comment: It's a little tricky to provide an example without pages of example data, since the time differences really only come into play on large inputs. But I'll see if I can't do something with `ExampleData` or some other function.

Comment: @march, I've added an example.

Comment: confirmed , roughly a factor of two.

Comment: Likely to do with the order intermediate results are generated and collected, but don't have time to deep-dive. Nonetheless, why on earth are you not memoizing here - will speed it up many orders of magnitude...

Comment: @ciao, hehe, there's a reason why I'm not memoizing, and it's because for some reason when I memoize suddenly I hit recursion limit. But I figured I'd focus on one question per question.

Comment: you can define a function like `s[n_,k_]:=s[n,k]=StirlingS2[n,k]` and use that to avoid repeated evals of stirling, but it doesn't buy you much. (note you cant use `RepeatedTiming` if you do that.) Otherwise I don't see how to use memoization.

Comment: @george2079, well, I assumed he meant `rankKRGS[string_] := rankKRGS[string] = ...`, but again, that hits recursion limit for some reason. I did try to memoize `StirlingS2`, but that gave me only marginal improvement.

Comment: It seems like you could  develop a forward (non recursive) calculation, get a value for first element, first two, and so on.  Sort of beside the point of the question to think of alternate approache though.

Comment: Maybe some sort of caching is going on?  Then if calculating `a` speed up calculating `b`, but not the reverse, `a+b` would be faster than `b+a`.  I tried to include `ClearSystemCache[]` in various places in the function, but I cannot make the timing difference go away.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the order in which [`StirlingS2`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StirlingS2) is evaluated with the first definition:

```
rankKRGS[{}] = 0;
rankKRGS[string_] := With[{n = Length@string, k = Max@string + 1, alone = !MemberQ[Most@string, Last@string]},
    rankKRGS@Most@string + If[alone, k StirlingS2[n - 1, k], Last@string StirlingS2[n - 1, k]]
]

data = {0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 6, 10, 11, 12, 12, 0, 7, 1, 8, 3, 13, 9, 6, 11, 14, 15, 
16, 17, 6, 18, 19, 20, 6, 21, 17, 22, 15, 23, 23, 15, 23, 22, 6, 24, 25, 6, 22, 17, 24, 6, 26, 17,
27, 28, 6, 24, 15, 27, 17, 29, 6, 25, 30, 6, 20, 15, 24, 24, 15, 23, 22, 6, 21, 28, 6, 31, 17, 27, 
6, 20, 15, 20, 24, 17, 27, 6, 25, 23, 6, 24, 31, 17, 6, 21, 19, 23, 32, 33, 6, 19, 23, 29, 6, 25, 
30, 6, 31, 19, 26, 15, 23, 22, 6, 23, 25, 24, 31, 15, 23, 22, 6, 24, 25, 6, 29, 25, 34};

stir = Flatten @ Last @ Reap @ TracePrint[
    rankKRGS[data],
    StirlingS2[__Integer],
    TraceAction->Sow
];
stir //Short
```

> {StirlingS2[0,1],StirlingS2[1,2],StirlingS2[2,2],StirlingS2[3,3],<<121>>,StirlingS2[125,34],StirlingS2[126,34],StirlingS2[127,35]}

Now consider the order in which [`StirlingS2`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StirlingS2) is evaluated with the second definition:

```
rankKRGS[{}] = 0;
rankKRGS[string_] := With[{n = Length@string, k = Max@string + 1, alone = !MemberQ[Most@string, Last@string]},
    If[alone, k StirlingS2[n - 1, k], Last@string StirlingS2[n - 1, k]] + rankKRGS@Most@string
]

stir2 = Flatten @ Last @ Reap @ TracePrint[
    rankKRGS[data],
    StirlingS2[__Integer],
    TraceAction->Sow
];
stir2 === Reverse[stir]
```

> True

The two are reversed. Now, let's time how long it takes to evaluate these [`StirlingS2`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StirlingS2) objects:

```
ReleaseHold[stir]; //AbsoluteTiming
ReleaseHold[stir2]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.001158, Null}
>
> {0.003476, Null}

I think the above difference in timing explains the difference you're seeing. I'm not sure what's going on internally in Mathematica, perhaps there is some kind of per evaluation cache that gets populated, and is helpful only when [`StirlingS2`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StirlingS2) is computed with increasingly larger arguments.